# Edit multiple MySQL rows using PHP where primary key is same for all rows

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I am referencing the URL http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mysql/php-mysql-edit-update-data/ to edit rows from a MySQL table. The page displays fine with the edit button besides each row. However, upon clicking any of the edit button on any of the rows, it shows input/edit for the last row.

The reason why this would be occurring maybe because we have primary key(auto-incremented) as "abc-2010-2011-1" (abc-2010-2011-2, abc-2010-2011-3) & not id. Secondly, there are multiple rows referencing the same primary key such as abc-2010-2011-1. So when we try editing the first row from the table, it tries editing/displays input for the last row of the array.

```
<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","app","abc123") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("quotation");
$serial=$objResult['serial_no'];
$parti=$objResult['particulars'];
    $qnt=$objResult['quantity'];
    $untp=$objResult['unit_price'];
$i=1;
    foreach(serial_no as $val) {
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE complete_qtn_no = '".$_GET["CusID[]"]. "' and     serial_no=$val[$i] ; ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
$i++;
}
if(!$objResult)
{
    echo "Quotation number not found =".$_GET["CusID"];
}
else
{
?>
```

Below is entries from table1,

```
+----+------------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id | to_addr                | app_date | subject_quote                      | serial_no | particulars | quantity | unit_price | tamount | delivery | payment   | complete_qtn_no   | tax_value1 | tax_value2 | tax1    | tax2    | net_total |
+----+------------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 79 | test | 01/06/11   | Quotation as per your requirements |         2 | TESTING2    |       78 |      98.56 | 7687.68 | 2 Days   | Immediate | ABC-QTN-2010-11-20 |         16 |          0 | 1230.03 |       0 |   8917.71 |
| 78 | test1 | 01/06/11   | Quotation as per your requirements |         1 | TESTING     |       16 |      78.89 | 1262.24 | 2 Days   | Immediate | ABC-QTN-2010-11-20 |          3 |         16 | 37.8672 | 201.958 |   1502.07 |
| 77 | test3|            | Quotation as per your requirements |         3 | Cable       |       68 |      89.76 | 6103.68 | 2 Days   | Immediate | ABC-QTN-2010-11-19 |          3 |       12.5 |  183.11 |  762.96 |   7049.75 |
| 76 | test4|            | Quotation as per your requirements |         2 | Motor       |       16 |       78.8 |  1260.8 | 2 Days   | Immediate | ABC-QTN-2010-11-19 |         16 |          0 | 201.728 |       0 |   1462.53 |
| 75 | test5 |            | Quotation as per your requirements |         1 | Pipe        |       10 |         15 |     150 | 2 Days   | Immediate | abc-QTN-2010-11-19 |          3 |         16 |     4.5 |      24 |     178.5 |
+----+------------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the same value then it is *not* a primary key. Besides, your table does have a Primary Key, it's called `id`.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your actual question? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's not even possible to have a primary key on a column that contains duplicate values. Am I correct in interpreting your information to mean that you are claiming the primary key for `table1` is the `complete_qtn_no` column?

Comment: Have your HTML generation script use the `id` field as the row identifier, instead of `complete_qtn_no`. That gives you the unique row identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ".$_GET["id"];
```